# CSV upload into SharePoint list from Ubuntu

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csv, ubuntu

I have a csv file in Ubuntu 16.04 version.  I want it to be upload into SharePoint list via power shell.

I come to know that [powershell core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-6) is avalable for this Ubuntu version... But I am not able to understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell core is probably not going to be your best option because the main SharePoint client libraries are not going to be compatible with it.

I'd suggest a Node.js app using PnPJS. here's a guide to getting started with that:

https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/documentation/getting-started/#connect-to-sharepoint-from-node

You're going to need to parse the CSV and upload the list items in a loop.